¿Como puedo poner los datos personales de un usuario cogiendolo de la base de datos?
Estoy haciendo una página web de compras para un proyecto de clase. Todo el html está, y estoy empezando a con los JSP, Servlets y base de datos creada por mi. El problema viene por que ahora mismo estoy haciendo el Servlet yJ JSP de inicio de sesión de un usuario. Por ejemplo, si el usuario hace click en la barra de navegación, en el apartado "Usuario", que debería mostrar los datos personales, esta le redirige al formulario para loguearse, si al loguearse la session es nula volverá a mostrar el formulario, si hay algun en la base de datos mostrará los datos personales. Pongo aqui el JSP llamado loginUsuario.jsp:
```
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" import="tienda.*" import="tienda.AccesoBD" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <title>Marvel Card Universe </title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="./img/logo.jpg" sizes="64x64">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos.css">
        </head>
        <body class="body">
            <mi-cabecera></mi-cabecera>
            <mi-menu></mi-menu>
        <%-- Utilizamos una variable en la sesión para informar de los mensajes de Error --%>
        <%
        String mensaje = (String)session.getAttribute("mensaje");

        if (mensaje != null) {
        %>
        <%-- Eliminamos el mensaje consumido --%>
        <%
            session.removeAttribute("mensaje");
        %>
        <h1> <%=mensaje%> </h1>
        <%
        }
        %>

        <%-- Si no hay usuario o el usuario no es válido --%>

        <%
        if ((session.getAttribute("usuario") == null) ||
            ((Integer)session.getAttribute("usuario") <=0 ))
        {
        %>
        <%-- Mostramos el formulario para la introducción del usuario y la clave --%>
        <div class="login">
            <div class="formlogin">
                  <form class="login-form" method="post" action="login.html">
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="./loginUsuario.jsp">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="usuario" name="usuario" required type="text"/>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="contraseña" required name="clave" type="password"/>
                    <button class="mb-2" type="submit" value="Entrar">Log in</button>
                    <button type="reset" value="Cancelar">Cancelar </button>
                    <br></br>
                    <p class="texto">Si no estas registrado <br> <a href="registro.html">Crea una cuenta</a></p>
                 </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        } else {
        %>
            <%-- Si existe un usuario, se muestran las opciones del apartado del usuario --%>
            <div class="login">
                <form class="login-form" method="get">
                    <div class="row formregistro">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombresesion">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" id="nombresesion" value="<%= usuarioBD.getNombre() %>" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" value="" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="apellidosesion">Apellido</label>
                                <input type="text" id="apellidosesion" value="de los Santos" readonly="readonly" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="usersesion">Usuario</label>
                                <input type="text" id="usersesion" value="ramos" readonly="readonly" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="telsesion">Teléfono</label>
                                <input type="text" id="telsesion" value="6338986205" readonly="readonly" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="emiliosesion">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" id="emiliosesion" value="loquesea" readonly="readonly" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="opcionesusuario">
                            <button class="botonregistro" type="button" value="submit" onclick="location.href='cambiar_datos.html'">Cambiar datos</button>
                            <button class="botonregistro" type="button" value="submit" onclick="location.href='index.html'">Cerrar Sesion</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </form>
            </div>

        <%
        }
        %>

        <mi-pie></mi-pie>
        <script src="./js/mis-etiquetas.js"></script>
    </body>



En teoría esto funciona cuando me logueo con el usuario creado en la BD me redirige a mis datos personales puestos en #value a mano. El problema viene cuando en esa página tengo que poner los datos personales que salen en la BD. He intentado poner esto en el else antes de los inputs:



        <%
            int usuario = (Integer) session.getAttribute("usuario");
            String clave = (String) session.getAttribute("clave");

            AccesoBD modelo = AccesoBD.getInstance();
            UsuarioBD usuarioBD = modelo.obtenerUsuario(usuario, clave);
        %>




Y como veis en AccesoBD he creado una función obtenerUsuario al que le pasas los dos strings la cual es esta: 



public UsuarioBD obtenerUsuario(String usuario, String clave) {
    abrirConexionBD();

    UsuarioBD user = new UsuarioBD();

    try {
        String con = "SELECT codigo, nombre, apellidos, telefono, domicilio FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND clave=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conexionBD.prepareStatement(con);
        ps.setString(1, usuario);
        ps.setString(2, clave);
        ResultSet resultado = ps.executeQuery();
        if (resultado.next()) {
            user.setCodigo(resultado.getInt("codigo"));
            user.setDireccion(resultado.getString("domicilio"));
            user.setEmail(resultado.getString("email"));
            user.setNombre(resultado.getString("nombre"));
            user.setApellidos(resultado.getString("apellidos"));
            user.setUser(usuario);
            user.setClave(clave);
            user.setTelefono(resultado.getString("telefono"));

            System.err.println(user.getNombre());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error ejecutando la consulta a la base de datos");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return user;




Debería funcionar, no hay ningún error. La cosa es que en las lineas que hago

    int usuario = (Integer) session.getAttribute("usuario");

Me dice que es nulo, cuando por ejemplo tengo la cookie de la session. Este es el error que me sale:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/loginUsuario.jsp] en línea [57]

54:     %>
55:         <%-- Si existe un usuario, se muestran las opciones del apartado del usuario --%>
56:         <%
57:             int usuario = (Integer) session.getAttribute("usuario");
58:             String clave = (String) session.getAttribute("clave");
59: 
60:             AccesoBD modelo = AccesoBD.getInstance();

causa raíz

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute(String)" is null

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo más fácil, o por que es null el usuario de la session a pesar de haber iniciado sesion y redirigiendome a donde tocaba?

